# How to make combo box selection similar to mobile device?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser, stylesheet

I need to give user interface similar to mobile device on IE,
when user clicks on combobox it should freeze the background gray and show the selection items in large fonts - once user selects item, he/she can go back to the page.

I want it in IE - end users are gonna use touch screen monitor for browsing the portal.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a library like [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) - you'll be able to get started quickly and you'll avoid having to deal with browser specific issues. Take a look at the [custom menus on the demo page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/forms/selects/index.html).